# How can I show some components when i click on a button?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

next to `Entertain` text, there is an icon, called `Button`,
When I click on that icon, I want those parts(netflix to twitch) to come that place.

How can I do that? I mean, i want those part to be hide at first, but after i click on that icon, it should come to that place.

Here are my code,

ThirdScreen.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, SafeAreaView, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from "react-native";

import Transfer from "../icons/transfer.svg";
import Entertain from "../icons/entertain.svg";
import Netflix from "../icons/netflix.svg";
import Button from "../icons/button.svg";
import Dribble from "../icons/dribble.svg";
import Spotify from "../icons/spotify.svg";
import Twitch from "../icons/twitch.svg";
import Bill from "../icons/bill.svg";
import Time from "../icons/time.svg";
import Home from "../icons/home.svg";
import User from "../icons/user.svg";
import Ratio from "../icons/ratio.svg";



const ThirdScreen = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor:"#ffffff"}}>
      <View style={{ alignItems: "center", padding: 20 }}>
        <Text style={styles.transaction}>Transaction History</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={{ padding: 10, }}>
        <View style={styles.rows}>
          <Text style={styles.bigBold}>Category</Text>
          <Text style={{ color: "#7cb3d9" }}>This week</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
          {/* Transfer */}
          <View style={[styles.elevation, {marginBottom:10,}]}>
            <View style={[styles.rows, {padding:5}]}>
              <View style={styles.iconText}>
                <Transfer height={30} width={22} fill={"#1E2439"} />
                <Text style={styles.bigBold}>Transfer</Text>
              </View>

              <View>
                <Button height={30} width={22} fill={"#1E2439"} />
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>

          {/* Entertain */}
          <View style={styles.elevation}>
            <View style={[styles.rows,{padding:5,}]}>
              <View style={styles.iconText}>
                <Entertain height={30} width={22} fill={"#1E2439"} />
                <Text style={styles.bigBold}>Entertain</Text>
              </View>

              <View>
                <Button height={30} width={22} fill={"#1E2439"} />
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>          

          <ScrollView style={{padding:10}}>
            {/* Netflix */}
            <View style={styles.rows}>
              <View style={styles.iconText}>
                <View style={[styles.iconBackground, { backgroundColor: "#ffd4d5"}]}>
                  <Netflix height={30} width={22} fill={"#1E2439"} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.entertainItems}>
                  <Text style={styles.entertainItemsText}>Netflix</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.grayText}>4 March</Text>
                </View>
              </View>

              <View style={{ flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
                <Text style={styles.redText}>-$8.99</Text>
                <Text style={styles.grayText}>Subscription</Text>
              </View>
            </View>

            {/* Dribble */}
            <View style={styles.rows}>
              <View style={styles.iconText}>
                <View style={[styles.iconBackground, { backgroundColor: "#fdd7e6" }]}>
                  <Dribble height={30} width={22} fill={"#1E2439"} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.entertainItems}>
                  <Text style={styles.entertainItemsText}>Dribble</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.grayText}>12 March</Text>
                </View>
              </View>

              <View style={{ flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
                <Text style={styles.redText}>-$120.00</Text>
                <Text style={styles.grayText}>Subscription</Text>
              </View>
            </View>

            {/* Spotify */}
            <View style={{ marginVertical: 10, flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
              <View style={styles.iconText}>
                <View style={[styles.iconBackground, { backgroundColor: "#d5ffd9" }]}>
                  <Spotify height={30} width={22} fill={"#1E2439"} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.entertainItems}>
                  <Text style={styles.entertainItemsText}>Spotify</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.grayText}>25 March</Text>
                </View>
              </View>

              <View style={{ flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
                <Text style={styles.redText}>-$9.99</Text>
                <Text style={styles.grayText}>Subscription</Text>
              </View>
            </View>

            {/* Twitch */}
            <View style={{ marginVertical: 10, flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
              <View style={styles.iconText}>
                <View style={[styles.iconBackground, { backgroundColor: "#efd6ff" }]}>
                  <Twitch height={30} width={22} fill={"#1E2439"} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.entertainItems}>
                  <Text style={styles.entertainItemsText}>Twitch</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.grayText}>25 March</Text>
                </View>
              </View>

              <View style={{ flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
                <Text style={styles.redText}>-$24.99</Text>
                <Text style={styles.grayText}>Subscription</Text>
              </View>
            </View>

          </ScrollView>

          {/* Bill */}
          <View style={styles.elevation}>
            <View style={[styles.rows, { padding: 5, }]}>
              <View style={styles.iconText}>
                <Bill height={30} width={22} fill={"#1E2439"} />
                <Text style={styles.bigBold}>Bill</Text>
              </View>

              <View>
                <Button height={30} width={22} fill={"#1E2439"} />
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
          

        </View>

        {/* Footer */}
        <View style={{flexDirection:"row", alignItems:"center", justifyContent:"space-between",marginHorizontal:35,}}>
          <Home height={30} width={22} fill={"#1E2439"} />
          <Ratio height={30} width={22} fill={"#1E2439"} />
          <Time height={30} width={22} fill={"#1E2439"} />
          <User height={30} width={22} fill={"#1E2439"} />

        </View>



      </View>

    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  transaction: {
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    letterSpacing: .5,
  },
  elevation: { 
    backgroundColor: "#fdfdfd", 
    elevation: 3, 
    height: 60, 
    borderRadius: 10, 
  },
  rows: { 
    flexDirection: "row", 
    alignItems: "center", 
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    marginVertical:10,
  },
  iconText: { 
    flexDirection: "row", 
    alignItems: "center", 
  },
  iconBackground: {
    height: 40,
    width: 40,
    borderRadius: 13,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  entertainItems: { 
    flexDirection: "column",
    marginLeft:20,
  },
  bigBold: {
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginLeft:15,
  },
  entertainItemsText: {
    fontSize:15,
    fontWeight:"bold",
  },
  redText : {
    color:"#e46e6a",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize:15,
  },
  grayText: {
    color: "#b2b4c3",
  },
})

export default ThirdScreen;
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach is to store a boolean `isShown` that is toggled when interacting with the button. Use the [`useState` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to store and update that boolean:

```
const ThirdScreen = () => {
  // Default to `false` so the section is initially hidden
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor:"#ffffff"}}>
      <View style={{ alignItems: "center", padding: 20 }}>
        <Text style={styles.transaction}>Transaction History</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={{ padding: 10, }}>
        {/* ... */}

        <View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
          {/* Transfer */}
          {/* ... */}

          {/* Entertain */}
          <View style={styles.elevation}>
            <View style={[styles.rows,{padding:5,}]}>
              <View style={styles.iconText}>
                <Entertain height={30} width={22} fill={"#1E2439"} />
                <Text style={styles.bigBold}>Entertain</Text>
              </View>

              <View>
                <Button
                  height={30}
                  width={22}
                  onClick={() => { setIsShown((currIsShown) => !currIsShown); }}
                  fill={"#1E2439"}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>          

          {/* Render the inner <ScrollView> only if `isShown` is true */}
          {isShown && (
            <ScrollView style={{padding:10}}>
              {/* Netflix */}
              {/* ... */}
            </ScrollView>
          )}

          {/* Bill */}
          {/* ... */}

        </View>

        {/* Footer */}
        {/* ... */}

      </View>

    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

Comment: You are amazing Sir, I appreciate it so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onClick event to change your required dom

For this first, make a state and set the initial value to false. Then use the onClick event and change the state using useEffect of setState.

At Last, change the CSS of the section to `display: "none"` on false and `display: "block"`( or other value ) on true